# How to set the windows Internet Explorer message to the front using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an option from the menu where the user will click on it to send an email. However if there is no default mail client installed, the following message will be displayed on the screen:

> Could not perform this operation because the default mail client is not properly installed.

My issue is that this message keeps displaying behind the windows form. Is it possible to bring that message in front of the screen? If yes, can anyone provide me some example.
I have tried using various method but I could not get it to work.

```
public static void Show(String p_File) {
    try {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = p_File;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;           

        process.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        new InformUser().Message(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are starting a process, instead of using the built in MessageBox?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned the code was already implemented when i started working on this project. So I am trying to find a way to bring that message to the front.

Comment: If all this method has to do is show a message to the user than I agree with Lithium. Get rid of all this code and use MessageBox.Show() instead. If there is a reason it has to be like this than find that reason and question it, not just take it for granted

Comment: Ok i will give it a try and thanks for the advice.